# Show/hide timeout event - unable to trigger click after amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting the following:
Have a Show/Hide Event that is supposed to trigger after a second when the page loads.  If the user clicks on the show/hide icon then it doesn't automatically trigger the timeout function.

When the Show/Hide Div appears it does the following:
- expand the div to be larger
- displays hidden content
- change out the icon

I have almost all of the functions working, except for the setTimeOut to work.  I managed to get it working on another page, but for some reason it's not working in this one.
Update:  The timeout function correctly works but as soon as it opens up, it immediately closes instead of remaining open.

Please advise!

Here's the code that I currently have:

JQuery:

```
setTimeout(function (f) {
    $('.show_hide_aboutus').click();
}, 1000);
//For About Us Show/hide
$('.show_hide_aboutus').click(function(f){

    f.preventDefault();
    clearTimeout(time); // cancels timeout
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle('fast',function() {
        $('.overlayAbout').toggleClass('animate', $(this).is(':visible'));
        if ( $('.animate').is(':visible') ){ // Open
            $('.showhideMenu').animate({ "margin-left": "-13px"}, 'fast');
            $('.showhideMenu').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.showWork').hide();
            $('.aboutContent').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.ourworkContent').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.overlayAbout').animate({ width: '29.5%', height: '100%'}, 'fast');   /*  */
            $('.infoicon').toggleClass('infoicon arrow-left'); /* hides the up arrow */
            $('.arrow-right-down').toggleClass('arrow-right-down arrow-right');    /* hides the up arrow */
        } else { // Close       
            $('.overlayAbout').animate({ width: 69, height: 69}, 'fast');   /*  */
            $('.ourworkContent').hide();
            $('.showWork').show();
            $('.aboutContent').hide();
            $('.arrow-left').toggleClass('arrow-left infoicon'); /* hides the up arrow */
            $('.arrow-right').toggleClass('arrow-right arrow-right-down');    /* hides the up arrow */
            $('.showhideMenu').hide();
        }

    }); /* slidingDiv Toggle */

}); /* show_hide click function */
```

HTML:

```
<div class="overlayAbout">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide_aboutus">
        <div class="infoicon"> </div>
        <div class="arrow-right-down"> </div>

        <div class="showWork">
            Back to <br/> <a href="/about-us" id="aboutusLink">about us</a>
        </div> <!--- showWork div link -->
    </a> <!-- show_hide -->
    <div class="slidingDiv">
        <div class="showhideMenu">
            Menu Stuff
        </div>
        <div class="large-9 columns margintop-small aboutContent">
            <div class="scrolling">
                Test setwlewjlj wlerjwlerj
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- large-9 columns margintop -->
</div> <!--slidingDiv  -->
</div> <!-- overlayAbout -->
```

CSS:

```
.slidingDiv { color: #4F4E4E; display: none;}
.overlayAbout{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 69px;
    height: 69px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #4F4E4E;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95);
    padding: 10px 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.showhideMenu{ display: none; }
.showWork{
    line-height: 15px;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.showWork a{ font-size: 9px; color: #334444; line-height:11px; }
.aboutContent{ display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your timeout function

```
$('show_hide_aboutus').click();
```

should be

```
$('.show_hide_aboutus').click();
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do you happen to know why it's not stopping after it opens up?  It just opens and closes immediately now.